# Telling C# that variable has the properties of an interface

Tags: c#, types, interface

I have the following interface:

```
public interface ISoftDeletable
{
    bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

And my entity:

```
public class Field : ISoftDeletable
{
    [Key]
    public int FieldID { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
...
```

In my generic repository i have:

```
...
if( entity is ISoftDeletable )
{
    entity.IsDeleted = true; // does not know entity is implementing ISoftDeletable, so is throwing error that i cannot set IsDeleted
}
...
```

but of course, c# does not know entity is implementing ISoftDeletable as entity is generic type.

How can i make C# know the IsDeleted property is okay to set?

Comment: `((ISoftDeletable)entity).IsDeleted = true` ? Also; something smells fishy about your setup, but I we don't have your interface and class schema to be able to tell what. You've edited in your interface, we still need to see the makeup of the `entity` class.

Comment: How are you declaring entity? What is its type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know anything more about your setup than what you've provided; but this feels fishy to me. It may not be, but I don't have enough of a picture to know.

To solve your immediate issue, you could cast the `entity` to the `ISoftDeletable` so that the `ISDeleted` property can be set:

```
((ISoftDeletable)entity).IsDeleted = true;
```

Again; something feels off about having to do that; but it's 9:47pm, so I'm not going to spend too much brain power to figure that out tonight.

Answer (score 6):

Based on your code I'd slightly change it to:

```
var softDelete = entity as ISoftDeletable;
if(softDelete != null)
{
  softDelete .IsDeleted = true; 
}
```

This code is a little more readable about what it is actually doing (IMO).

Comment: `(entity as ISoftDeletable)?.IsDeleted = true;` <-- will this work as well?

Comment: @zerkms I'm not sure what the `?` is for, so I believe that it can't be compiled.  Removing the `?` is also harmful, because it will fail with a `NullReferenceException` if it can't be cast as `ISoftDeletable`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips it's a single `?.` operator.

Comment: @Dan-o well, it's not :-)

Comment: heh.  Hatfield, meet McCoy.

Comment: @zerkms not [compiling for me for .Net 4.5 or Roslyn beta](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7ih8DU).

Comment: @ErikPhilips it requires at least v4.5.1 and C# 6

Comment: @zerkms your code gives "Internal compiler error: null propagating operator assignment". The `?.` operator is intended for "r-values", not "l-values". It causes the whole expression to evaluate to `null` if some early middle part of it evaluates to `null`, rather than throwing an exception. In your case what would happen? If `entity` is not an `ISoftDeletable`, you would end up with `null.IsDeleted = true`, which is what you would have had anyway without the operator.

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, the C# type system does not understand that in `if (x is X) { (1) }` that `x` has type `X` or has a subtype of `X` in `(1)`. This may not even be a safe assumption in C#, I do not know (concurrency?).

Instead, you might write this.

```
if (entity is ISoftDeletable) {
    ((ISoftDeletable)entity).IsDeleted = true;
}
```

This has the unfortunate consequence of casting `entity` twice, once for the branch condition and again to set `IsDeleted`. The cost of casting can be non-trivial (I'll let you decide for your case). Here is another variation that does not do this.

```
var deletableEntity = entity as ISoftDeletable;
if (deletableEntity != null) {
    deletableEntity.IsDeleted = true;
}
```

Comment: It's not actually casting twice, because `entity is ISoftDeletable` is not a cast.  But it is checking the type twice, which is of course why the `as` operator was added to the language.

Comment: I agree that `entity is ISoftDeletable` is not a cast but it requires much of the same work of a cast -- determining if the object is a valid instance of the type, which can be a non-trivial cost. This is only what I recall from past knowledge and I would recommend referring to documentation or at least the generated MSIL if you want to be certain.

Comment: Here is the MSIL opcode [castclass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.castclass(v=vs.110).aspx), emitted for doing casting, and opcode [isinst](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.isinst(v=vs.110).aspx), emitted for doing `x is X`. You might have to lift the hood on the VM to really find out what the costs are -- I do not personally know or recall where more documentation can be found.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `as`:

```
var maybeSoftDeletable = entity as ISoftDeletable;
if (maybeSoftDeletable != null)
   maybeSoftDeletable.IsDeleted = true;
```

`maybeSoftDeletable` will be `null` if `entity` is not an `ISoftDeletable`, or otherwise will be an `ISoftDeletable` reference to the same object.

As per George's answer, you can also cast:

```
var definitelyASoftDeletable = (ISoftDeletable)entity;
definitelyASoftDeletable.IsDeleted = true;
```

The main difference is whether you know `entity` is of the type or not. If `entity` is allowed to be one or not, then use `as`. If `entity` is supposed to be one, then use a cast, which will cause an exception if it violates that rule.

UPDATE: lately I've been using some `Maybe` and `MaybeAs` extension methods, which I'm loving so far:

```
public static void MaybeAs<T>(
   this object pObject,
   Action<T> pAction
) {
   var maybeT = pObject as T;
   if (maybeT == null)
      return;
   var t = maybeT;

   pAction(t);
}

// and one for functions
public static TResult MaybeAs<TObject, TResult>(
   this object pObject,
   Func<TObject, TResult> pFunc
) where TObject : class
where TResult: class {
   var maybeT = pObject as TObject;
   if (maybeT == null)
      return null;
   var t = maybeT;

   return pFunc(t);
}

// to allow for primitive return values
public static TResult MaybeAs<TObject, TResult>(
   this object pObject,
   Func<TObject, TResult> pFunc,
   TResult pValueWhenNot
) where TObject : class {
   var maybeT = pObject as TObject;
   if (maybeT == null)
      return pValueWhenNot;
   var t = maybeT;

   return pFunc(t);
}
```

Used like:

```
entity.MaybeAs<ISoftDeletable>(softDeletable => softDeletable.IsDeleted = true);
```

Comment: I am just wondering: what is the reasoning behind copying the `maybeT` variable to `t`? Why aren't you calling directly `pAction(maybeT)` / `pFunc(maybeT)`?

Comment: In addition, the code will not compile unless you add type constraints to the method signatures (`where T : class`, `where TObject : class` respectively). The first `return` statement in the `TResult MaybeAs<TObject, TResult>` overload should be `return default(TResult)`:

Comment: @PaloMraz It's just a rule I use in my code. Something prefixed with "maybe" might be `null`. Once I've confirmed that it isn't `null`, I copy it to a variable that doesn't have a `maybe` prefix. Saying `pAction(maybeT)` implies that the variable might be `null`, which we know it isn't at that point.

Comment: @PaloMraz You're right about the constraints; I had written these from memory. I updated the code.